# change the parameter of link to be looking like folder

Tags: php, .htaccess

How can I change the link of my website to be something like this:

```
example.com/en 
example.com/fr
example.com/et
```

I have a `lang?=something` parameter and I need to convert my link from `example.com/index.php?lang=en&so=so` to   `example.com/en/index.php&so=so`

my htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /   

# empty url -> redirect to en/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !lang=(en|ar)
RewriteRule ^$ en/ [R=301,L]

# url is ONLY '/en' or '/de' -> redirect to /en/ or /de/ (adding slash)
RewriteRule ^(en|ar)$  $1/ [R=301,L]

# now all urls have en/ de/ -> parse them
RewriteRule ^(en|ar)/(.*)$  $2?lang=$1&%{query_STRING} [L]
# no "R=301" here --------------------------------------^
```

This is my code it is working very well but the problem is I would like to redirect the page to the correct link automatically not manually.